# C# based Windows Service - Tries to do JIT Debugging in production

Tags: c#, windows-services, jit

I am getting this error in my event logs for a service I put into production:

> An unhandled win32 exception occurred
>   in RivWorks.FeedHandler.exe [5496].
>   Just-In-Time debugging this exception
>   failed with the following error:
>   Debugger could not be started because
>   no user is logged on.

I have it installed and running under a Win NT global account.  I have no idea why it is trying to drop into debugging mode.  It was built under the Release model.  Running on the 4.0 Framework.

When I run on my dev machine, via an EXE entry point instead of the WinSvc entry point, everything runs just fine - BUT - I am already in "debug" mode.

Any ideas of what to look for?

---

2010-10-21 - NOTE - Changed the code base.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using sysIO = System.IO;
using RivWorks.FeedHandler;
using System.Collections;

namespace RivWorks.FeedHandler.Service
{
    public partial class FeedListener : ServiceBase
    {
        #region Declarations
        private List<string> _keys = new List<string>();
        private System.Threading.Timer _clock = null;
        private FileSystemWatcher _watcher;
        private BackgroundWorker _worker;
        private Queue<string> _queue = new Queue<string>();
        private bool _isDequeueing = false;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public FeedListener()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Start/Stop
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                WriteToEventLog("Enter Start", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                _keys.AddRange(new string[] { "csv", "xml", "zip", "rivx" });

                _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                _worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(BackgroundWorkerDoWork);
                _worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(BackgroundWorkerProgressChanged);
                _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(BackgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted);

                _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(AppSettings.Default.FTPRootPath, "*.*");
                _watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
                _watcher.NotifyFilter = sysIO.NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | sysIO.NotifyFilters.FileName | sysIO.NotifyFilters.LastAccess | sysIO.NotifyFilters.CreationTime | sysIO.NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
                _watcher.Created += new sysIO.FileSystemEventHandler(fileCreatedOrChanged);
                _watcher.Changed += new sysIO.FileSystemEventHandler(fileCreatedOrChanged);
                _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                // check every 15 minutes...
                _clock = new System.Threading.Timer(Tick, null, 0, 900000);
                WriteToEventLog("Exit Start", EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                this.Stop();
            }
        }
        protected override void OnStop()  
        {
            try
            {
                _watcher.Dispose();
                _watcher = null;
                _clock.Dispose();
                _clock = null;
                _worker.Dispose();
                _worker = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Event Handlers
        void fileCreatedOrChanged(object sender, sysIO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                WriteToEventLog("Enter fileCreatedOrChanged", EventLogEntryType.Information);

                if (!_queue.Contains(e.FullPath))
                    _queue.Enqueue(e.FullPath);
                if (!_isDequeueing)
                    DeQueue();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Do work on another Thread
        void BackgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                WriteToEventLog("Enter BackgroundWorkerDoWork", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

                WriteToEventLog("Create Handler", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                RivWorks.FeedHandler.Library.Handler handler = new RivWorks.FeedHandler.Library.Handler(Convert.ToBoolean(AppSettings.Default.InProduction), AppSettings.Default.ArchivePath);

                WriteToEventLog("Setup Handler", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                handler.Keys = _keys;
                handler.RootDirectory = AppSettings.Default.RootDirectory;
                handler.FtpPath = AppSettings.Default.FTPRootPath;
                handler.WorkPath = AppSettings.Default.WorkPath;
                handler.ArchivePath = AppSettings.Default.ArchivePath;
                handler.EmailHost = AppSettings.Default.EmailHost;
                handler.EmailPassword = AppSettings.Default.EmailPassword;
                handler.EmailUser = AppSettings.Default.EmailUser;
                handler.ErrorNotificationRecipients = AppSettings.Default.ErrorNotificationRecipients;
                handler.InProduction = Convert.ToBoolean(AppSettings.Default.InProduction);

                Library.DTO.FileHandler fileHandler = new Library.DTO.FileHandler(handler.FtpPath, handler.WorkPath, handler.ArchivePath, (string)e.Argument);

                WriteToEventLog("Call Handler.Execute", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                handler.Execute(bw, e, fileHandler);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                WriteToEventLog("Exit BackgroundWorkerDoWork", EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
        }
        void BackgroundWorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.ProgressPercentage >= 100)
                {
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }
        void BackgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Cancelled)
                {
                    WriteToEventLog("Cancelled.", EventLogEntryType.Warning);
                    if (e.Error != null)
                    {
                        WriteToEventLog(e.Error, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    }
                }
                else if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    WriteToEventLog(e.Error, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    WriteToEventLog("Successfully completed.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private void Tick(object data)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_isDequeueing)
                {
                    WriteToEventLog("Enter Tick.  FTP Root = " + AppSettings.Default.FTPRootPath, EventLogEntryType.Information);

                    foreach (string key in _keys)
                    {
                        List<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(AppSettings.Default.FTPRootPath), "*." + key, SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
                        foreach (string fileName in files)
                        {
                            if (File.Exists(fileName))
                            {
                                // Toss this file name into the Queue...
                                WriteToEventLog("Call _queue.Enqueue(" + fileName + ")", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                                if (!_queue.Contains(fileName))
                                    _queue.Enqueue(fileName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // Now, start handling the list of files...
                    DeQueue();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                WriteToEventLog("Exit Tick", EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
        }
        private void DeQueue()
        {
            try
            {
                _isDequeueing = true;

                WriteToEventLog("Enter DeQueue", EventLogEntryType.Information);

                while (_queue.Count > 0)
                {
                    string queuedFile = _queue.Dequeue();
                    WriteToEventLog("DeQueued " + queuedFile, EventLogEntryType.Information);

                    bool isValid = false;
                    foreach (string key in _keys)
                    {
                        if (Path.GetExtension(queuedFile).Replace(".", "").Equals(key, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                            isValid = true;
                    }

                    if (isValid)
                    {
                        // Now, spin up a new thread and do the work on the file, based on file type...
                        WriteToEventLog("Call RunWorkerAsync", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                        string UserName = Path.GetDirectoryName(queuedFile).Replace(AppSettings.Default.FTPRootPath, "").Replace("\\", "");
                        int i = 0;
                        DateTime sTime = DateTime.Now;
                        DateTime eTime = DateTime.Now;
                        _worker.RunWorkerAsync(queuedFile);  // goes to BackgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) //

                        while(_worker.IsBusy)
                        {
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                            i++;
                        }
                        eTime = DateTime.Now;
                        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(eTime.Ticks - sTime.Ticks);
                        string msg = String.Format("Import for {0} started at {1} and ended at {2}.  It took {3} cycles and the elapsed time was {4}:{5}:{6}.", UserName, sTime, eTime, i, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
                        WriteToEventLog(msg, EventLogEntryType.Information);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                _isDequeueing = false;
                WriteToEventLog("Exit DeQueue", EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
        }
        private void WriteToEventLog(Exception ex, EventLogEntryType eventLogEntryType)
        {
            try
            {
                string message = string.Empty;
                string sTrace = ex.StackTrace;
                while (ex != null)
                {
                    message = message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message;
                    ex = ex.InnerException;
                }
                message = message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + sTrace;

                WriteToEventLog(message, eventLogEntryType);
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex2.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }
        private void WriteToEventLog(string message, EventLogEntryType eventLogEntryType)
        {
            try
            {
                this.EventLog.WriteEntry(message, eventLogEntryType);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

---

2010-10-20 - NOTE - Added the Service code file.  Maybe there is an elementary mistake in here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using sysIO = System.IO;
using RivWorks.FeedHandler;

namespace RivWorks.FeedHandler.Service
{
    public partial class FeedListener : ServiceBase
    {
        #region Declarations
        private List<string> _keys = new List<string>();
        private System.Threading.Timer _clock = null;
        private FileSystemWatcher _watcher;
        private BackgroundWorker _worker;
        static private bool _isBusy = false;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public FeedListener()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Start/Stop
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                _keys.AddRange(new string[] { "csv", "xml", "zip", "rivx" });

                _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                _worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(BackgroundWorkerDoWork);
                _worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(BackgroundWorkerProgressChanged);
                _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(BackgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted);

                _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(AppSettings.Default.FTPRootPath, "*.*");
                _watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
                _watcher.NotifyFilter = sysIO.NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | sysIO.NotifyFilters.FileName | sysIO.NotifyFilters.LastAccess | sysIO.NotifyFilters.CreationTime | sysIO.NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
                _watcher.Created += new sysIO.FileSystemEventHandler(fileCreatedOrChanged);
                _watcher.Changed += new sysIO.FileSystemEventHandler(fileCreatedOrChanged);
                _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                // check every 5 minutes...
                _clock = new System.Threading.Timer(Tick, null, 0, 300000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                this.Stop();
            }
        }
        protected override void OnStop()  
        {
            try
            {
                _watcher.Dispose();
                _watcher = null;
                _clock.Dispose();
                _clock = null;
                _worker.Dispose();
                _worker = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Event Handlers
        void fileCreatedOrChanged(object sender, sysIO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DTO.BackgroundWorkerEventArgs eventArgs = new DTO.BackgroundWorkerEventArgs();
                sysIO.WatcherChangeTypes myType = e.ChangeType;

                bool isValid = false;
                foreach (string key in _keys)
                {
                    if (Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath).Replace(".", "").Equals(key, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                        isValid = true;
                }

                if (isValid)
                {
                    eventArgs.PathAndFile = e.FullPath;
                    eventArgs.Key = Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath).ToLower().Replace(".", "");
                    eventArgs.FileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath);
                    eventArgs.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath);
                    eventArgs.UserName = Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath).Replace(AppSettings.Default.FTPRootPath, "").Replace("\\", "");
                    eventArgs.IsRunning = true;

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);

                    // Now, spin up a new thread and do the work on the file, based on file type...
                    _isBusy = true;
                    _worker.RunWorkerAsync(eventArgs);  // goes to BackgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) //
                    int i = 0;
                    DateTime sTime = DateTime.Now;
                    DateTime eTime = DateTime.Now;
                    while (_isBusy)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        i++;
                    }
                    eTime = DateTime.Now;
                    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(eTime.Ticks - sTime.Ticks);
                    string msg = String.Format("Import for {0} started at {1} and ended at {2}.  It took {3} cycles and the elapsed time was {4}:{5}:{6}.", eventArgs.UserName, sTime, eTime, i, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
                    WriteToEventLog(msg, EventLogEntryType.Information);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Do work on another Thread
        void BackgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                RivWorks.FeedHandler.Handler handler = new RivWorks.FeedHandler.Handler();
                BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

                handler.Execute(bw, e);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                _isBusy = false;
            }
        }
        void BackgroundWorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.ProgressPercentage >= 100)
                {
                    _isBusy = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }
        void BackgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Cancelled)
                {
                    WriteToEventLog("Cancelled.", EventLogEntryType.Warning);
                    if (e.Error != null)
                    {
                        WriteToEventLog(e.Error, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    }
                }
                else if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    WriteToEventLog(e.Error, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    WriteToEventLog("Successfully completed.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                }
                _isBusy = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private void Tick(object data)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string key in _keys)
                {
                    List<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(AppSettings.Default.FTPRootPath), "*." + key, SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
                    foreach (string fileName in files)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        if (File.Exists(fileName))
                        {
                            DateTime lat = File.GetLastWriteTime(fileName);
                            try
                            {
                                File.SetLastWriteTime(fileName, DateTime.Now);
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                // just catch and ignore with a short pause...
                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }
        private void WriteToEventLog(Exception ex, EventLogEntryType eventLogEntryType)
        {
            try
            {
                string message = string.Empty;
                string sTrace = ex.StackTrace;
                while (ex != null)
                {
                    message = message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message;
                    ex = ex.InnerException;
                }
                message = message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + sTrace;

                this.EventLog.WriteEntry(message, eventLogEntryType);
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex2, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }
        private void WriteToEventLog(string message, EventLogEntryType eventLogEntryType)
        {
            try
            {
                this.EventLog.WriteEntry(message, eventLogEntryType);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though it's running as a release exe, you'll still be given the option to attach to a debugger when the app crashes... you just won't see debug symbols, just assembly :)

I believe it's the Dr. Watson process that catches app errors for debugging... Because your app is a service, Dr. Watson can't interact with the desktop, giving you the error you see.  You can go to the service properties and mark "allow service to interact with the desktop", found on the LogOn tab, which should then give you a Dr. Watson popup when the app crashes.

Steps to disable Dr. Watson are here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188296

If you want to debug the app on the server, you can enable remote debugging on the server, and attach Visual Studio to the process... if you want to try this, I can give you more tips for debugging a windows service remotely.

HTH,
James

*** Edit ***
Based on the code you provided, I'd look at the following areas:

1. Is `AppSettings.Default.FTPRootPath` set correctly in `App.Config`?
2. Are there changes happening to that directory immediately when the service starts?  You have a timer commented as "check every five minutes", which is a little confusing, because the `FileSystemWatcher` will start receiving events as soon as you set `EnableRaisingEvents` to true.  So the issue could actually lie within `fileCreatedOrChanged`
3. Along those lines, you have one `BackgroundWorker` servicing multiple events, and worse, you're firing the handler asynchronously.  This is my most likely suspect, because if you call `_worker.RunWorkerAsync()` again while the first job is running, you'll get an `InvalidOperationException`.  Though I'm not sure why you wouldn't see that in the log
4. You're using the timer to update the last write time for all files in the watched directory, and you do this every five seconds.  This seems like a very bad idea... I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  This will fire your `FileSystemWatcher`'s changed event, which would explain why you're crashing less than 10 seconds after you start (the timer's initial tick is set to fire immediately, meaning five seconds later you're changing all the file times, triggering the `FileSystemWatcher` multiple times shortly after that)

So my best guess is that within five seconds, you've begun firing multiple `RunWorkAsync()` calls on the same `BackgroundWorker`, which is a no-no : )

Setting the static variable _isBusy to true/false isn't reliable because you're multi-threading with the BackgroundWorkers... you need to use a Mutex or some other lock, but doesn't that really defeat the purpose of using a BackgroundWorker?

Also, if you wanted to use something like an isBusy flag, it would have to look more like:

```
while (_isBusy) {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}

_isBusy = true;
_worker.RunWorkerAsync(eventArgs);
```

You need _isBusy to be false before you try to launch the Background worker... the way you have it, if the event fires 100 times, you'll make 100 calls.

The easiest solution to your problem would be to create a new BackgroundWorker in the fileCreatedOrChanged method every time the event fires... there's overhead involved in creating so many new threads, but if the work being done in this method is significant, it will be worth the overhead.

You might be able to rely on the built-in BackgroundWorker.IsBusy property, but again, I'd have to question the benefit of asynchronous threading if you're just going to block until the background worker completes.

**** Edit **** 

I understand now what you're trying to accomplish with the initial file timestamp changes... I think you would do better to leave the timestamps alone, but just run through a startup loop to process existing files.  You can spawn a background worker thread for each one, just like you do on the FileSystemWatcher nofications.  The way you're handling it is deliberately creating a side-effect to trigger the result you want.

I'm losing track a little bit in the growing complexity... the whole queue/dequeue thing might be unnecessary.  Or maybe I just am not seeing a need that is truly there.  Again, what strikes me is that you are launching the background worker asynchronously, then putting the main thread to sleep until it finishes.

When you put the main thread to sleep, no events will get processed, so you are truly throttling the multi-threading to one thread.  I see that you want to write to the event log how long it took for a thread to finish.  I will start a second answer to address that if I get a chance to, but the gist of it is to pass a `Stopwatch` class (which will give you an accurate count of either milliseconds or CPU ticks that pass during an operation) to the DoWorkEventArgs.Result property.

But the code you requested!  Basically, wherever you decide to call `_worker.RunWorkerAsync(queuedFile)`, rather than run one class-level `BackgroundWorker` create a new one each time.  Pass all the same parameters for the event handlers, etc.  Your service entry point would drop all the BGW references and look like:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        _keys.AddRange(new string[] { "csv", "xml", "zip", "rivx" });

        _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(AppSettings.Default.FTPRootPath, "*.*");
        _watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        _watcher.NotifyFilter = sysIO.NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | sysIO.NotifyFilters.FileName | sysIO.NotifyFilters.LastAccess | sysIO.NotifyFilters.CreationTime | sysIO.NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        _watcher.Created += new sysIO.FileSystemEventHandler(fileCreatedOrChanged);
        _watcher.Changed += new sysIO.FileSystemEventHandler(fileCreatedOrChanged);
        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        WriteToEventLog("Exit Start", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }
```

and the code where you run the BGW asynchronously would become:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(BackgroundWorkerDoWork);
worker.ProgressChanged += BackgroundWorkerProgressChanged;        // Note you don't need
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted;  // the 'new' here

worker.RunWorkerAsync(queuedFile);  // goes to BackgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) //
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I have extensive error handling through my app and was expecting it to write to the event logs on any and all errors!  This is a headless server and does not have VS or remote debugging installed (that I am aware of).  I am probably at the point where I will have to try remote debugging though I am doubtful I can ever attach as the longest it has run is 9 seconds before popping this JIT error.

Comment: Using the "allow service to interact with the desktop" option did not change anything.  I still see the 2 event logs (start up successful & JIT Debugging error plus shut down of event).

Comment: There is a trick I use to debug a service... in the service start code, I write while(true){} as the first statement.  Then, when I attach to the service, I can pause and manually set the next statement to the next line and debug from there.  You'll have to increase the start timeout for the service significantly to give you time to attach.

Comment: Remote debugging can be run from the server pretty easily... you can even run it from a network share, or steps to install it as a service are here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx

Comment: 1. - Yes, AppSettings is correct.  2. - The service may start with stale files in the FTP directories.  Therefore, I do an initial scan to get them to fire off the file watcher event.  3. - Would love to fire off multiple background workers, do you have any suggestions/samples?  :)   4. - The timer was added as a last ditch attempt to process in stale files...     I've dropped the _isBusy static variable and am now using the BackgroundWorker's IsBusy flag.  This flag is set within the thread so is supposed to be safe to use.  **(See edits)**

Comment: BTW - After much Event Logging and changing the base code for the Service I finally discovered what was causing the error.  Our company has a home grown Logger that was written in VB 2005 (nothing wrong with VB!).  It did not have a way to pass in the target directory and instead used the Application path for the target directory.  When called from the Service, the Logger was trying to write to **C:\Windows\System32!!**  This directory is off limits.  It seems that Windows Services treat DLLs as if they belonged there and supplies that path as the App Path.  So I fixed that and now it works.

Comment: Looking at generating a new BW for each file event raised as that is more what I want.  However, when in debug mode, stepping seems to step from thread to thread quite randomly and I lose where I am at for a single file.  I also want to ensure each thread is 100% compartmented so there is no bleed over between them.  Just call me a thread newbie and you will be close.  :)

Comment: Debugging a multi-threaded app is a challenge!!  No doubt about that.  You can open the thread-window in the debugger and pick which thread you're debugging, but it's true, you will still get interrupted with every breakpoint that is hit.  Debugging in this case is better left as a stop-when-you-crash exercise.   Or, for debugging purposes, what I sometimes do is put in a class-level Mutex, and force my event handlers to wait on the mutex before spawning another thread.

Comment: Also, if you really want to get into multi-threading, take a look at the System.Threading.Thread class.  A BackgroundWorker is packaged for easy use, but a `Thread` class gives you much more power and flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer credit : )  If you want to know more about passing a stopwatch to the completed event, ask a new question and drop the link in here... this thread is getting full : )  But taking away the need to time the completion will let you drop the sleep and de-throttle your multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that it couldn't attach a debugger to let you inspect the exception. This is completely unrelated to the fact that this is a release build. Release build and debug builds can both be debugged (fortunately!).

Debugging services is a little different from debugging regular applications. Please check [this guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824344) for some advice.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I checked the guide and tried to do as it says.  Unfortunately, the service only ever runs for a few seconds before bailing out again so I cannot get attached.

Comment: @Keith: Did you read the part about how to use gflags to start the service with the debugger attached?

Comment: Yes I did.  Our server is not setup for remote debugging and I am going through the red-tape to prove it won't wreck everything.  However, I did find the cause of the problem (see comments in the accepted answer).